# Associativity with one operation or two (or more) operations

Tags: abstract-algebra, terminology, definition

It seems to me there are different 'types' of associative law that are all said to simply have the property of associativity.

For example this term is applied if we are only considering one operator e.g. $(x \circ y) \circ z = x \circ (y \circ z)$, or, as in the case of a vector space, two operators e.g. $\lambda (\mu v) = (\lambda \mu)v$ where $\lambda,\mu$ are scalars and $v$ is a vector. Presumably this would extend to three or more operators.

My question is: have there ever been different names for these seemingly different kinds of associative law?

For examples of this usage, please see [here](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/do_you_know/mul_scal1.shtml) and [here](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Gg3Uj1GkHK8C&pg=PA130&dq=linear+algebra+associativity+scalar+vector&hl=en&sa=X&ei=o2cpUcPhA8aW0QW8p4GQCw&ved=0CDEQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=linear%20algebra%20associativity%20scalar%20vector&f=false).

Comment: Did you see this called associativity somewhere?  I'm almost sure I've never seen it called that.

Comment: For my responses to this comment, please see below Tara B's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the question how the equation $\lambda(\mu v) = (\lambda \mu) v$ in the definition of a vector space is related to the usual notion of associativity:

The usual notion of associativity of a multiplication $*$ says that $L_x \circ L_y = L_{x*y}$, where $L_x$ is the operator which multiplies with $x$ on the left. But in case of a vector space, we also have, for every scalar $\lambda$, an operator (called homothety) which multiplies with $\lambda$ on the left, and we get the same equation.

Even more generally, let $X$ be a set and $M$ be a magma (a set equipped with a binary operation). Then an action of $M$ on $X$ is a function $M \times X \to X$, denoted by $(m,x) \mapsto m*x$, which satisfies $m*(n*x)=(m*n)*x$. This can be equivalently described as a homomorphism of magmas $M \to \mathrm{End}(X), m \mapsto L_m$.

Then the multiplication $M \times M \to M$ is an action if and only if the binary operation on $M$ is associative, i.e. $M$ is a semigroup. But also other actions are possible. If $M$ is a monoid there is a similar definition (requiring $1*x=x$), actually more generally for monoid objects in a monoidal category. For the monoidal category of abelian groups this precisely yields the notion of a module over a ring, in particular vector spaces.

Conclusion: The notion of an *action* is the most general incarnation of associativity.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, just something I am unclear about: you say the action is a function defined by $(m,x) \mapsto m*x$, but then you say it satisfies $m*(n*x)=(m*n)*x$. However I don't see how $(m*n)$ is defined here as $m$ and $n$ are both elements of $M$?

Comment: @user50229: I'm pretty sure $*$ must be representing the binary operation of $M$ there.

Comment: @Martin It's been a while since I asked this question, but I've recently seen this 'associativity' described as the 'morphism property' - is this something you recognise?

Answer (score 0):

Associativity is a property of a single binary operation.  I don't think I had seen the term 'associative' used for a relationship between multiple operations (but I have now from your comments below).

I'm not sure if there's a general term for things like your example of $\lambda(\mu v) = (\lambda\mu)v$.  In that particular case, Wikipedia calls it 'compatibility of scalar multiplication with field multiplication'.

Comment: I have seen it in a few places and in lecture notes, after a quick Google search I found an example on [this page](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/do_you_know/mul_scal1.shtml)

Comment: I also see several linear algebra texts on Google books have this terminology [for example this](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Gg3Uj1GkHK8C&pg=PA130&dq=linear+algebra+associativity+scalar+vector&hl=en&sa=X&ei=o2cpUcPhA8aW0QW8p4GQCw&ved=0CDEQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=linear%20algebra%20associativity%20scalar%20vector&f=false) (This was the first book I got in the list of results.)

Comment: Hmm, interesting.

Comment: Well, does my answer answer your question about whether there have ever been different names for this type of 'associativity', or are you looking for something more complete?

Comment: I don't think you have answered my question, you said you didn't know if there was a general term. I would like someone who has seen this referred to as 'associativity' (as in the sources I gave), and either agrees or disagrees with it, to give their opinion.

Comment: @whoever downvoted:  You're unlikely to see this, but I just want to know whether you did mean to vote down my answer, because I saw my rep go up by 10 and then immediately back down to 2 less than before, and I thought you might (like me) have thought that clicking the down arrow was the way to reverse an accidental upvote.
I'm not complaining about the downvote if you did mean it, just checking whether other people make the same mistake I made with the voting!  (See my [meta question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8635/reversing-accidental-upvote).)

Comment: an action is needed here @TaraB, so +1